# Compile python dolfin with cgal

Tags: python, compilation, cgal

I wanted to install `fenics` and used the suggested commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fenics-packages/fenics
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fenics
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

During the installation I got the error:

```
Processing triggers for python-support (1.0.15) ...
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scitools/pyreport/main.py:268: SyntaxWarning: import * 
only allowed at module level
  def __call__(self, name, globals=None, locals=None, fromlist=None,
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scitools/pyreport/main.py:285: SyntaxWarning: import * 
only allowed at module level
  def __call__(self, name, globals=None, locals=None,
```

When conducting the following commands in a python shell:

```
from dolfin import*
has_cgal()
```

I get

```
False
```

I guess I have to compile `Dolfin` together with `CGAL` but how?
Any ideas?